# jQuery Smart Wizard - Reset certain steps

Tags: smart-wizard

Im using this in my MVC project:
http://techlaboratory.net/jquery-smartwizard#func-stepstate

There it's explained how to disable or hide steps, but how to reset / mark undone some specific steps?

The reason i need this: I have 7 steps and if he user goes back for example to step 3 and changes something all the following steps have to be resetted, making the user go through them again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to do it!

First i add an id to every step like:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#step-1" id="stepper-step-1">
```

Then i can remove done class to mark them undone:

```
$('#stepper-step-1').removeClass('done')
$('#stepper-step-2').removeClass('done')
$('#stepper-step-3').removeClass('done')
```